# Event ExportData in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

im searching an example for using the exportData event in Highcharts

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.exportData

I do not find any example, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `exporting` and `export-data` modules and click for example 'View data table' in the context menu:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        exportData: function() {
            alert('export data!');
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/50vx6ad8/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview